# How is mutable data reloaded when only several amounts of data changes after updating the database? (iOS)

Tags: php, ios, mysql, hash, afnetworking

I have about 200 records that I am redownloading from the server everytime a view controller is displayed as I need to display the most up to date information - related to the 200 customers' balance. Each record also contains other details about the customer which could change too.

The first thing I thought of was to create a hash serverside everytime a value in the customer database was changed which would then be returned everytime I ask for the customer database to display on the client side. I would store this locally, and before redownloading the database from the server I would do a quick check to see if the hashes matched - and to only redownload if the hashes didnt match.

I feel this to be inefficient - although a little better than my current situation since the hash would help avoid a number of redownloads, but the customer records can change all the time - say 2-3 records every hour or so.

What's the best way of updating the client side database without having to redownload the entire database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get and save server time for each table update, when you want to check for updates in server then you need to send this server time along with the request, then server will send you any updated data which is updated after the time stamp you sent to server. once you get data you need to update if that record already exist else insert. hope this might help you.

Comment: It definitely does help. I realised the other day that this way is a good way to go about solving the problem. I was originally complicating the issue for nothing when an `update_at` field will suffice. I also remembered asking a question like this, and thought I'd mark it answered :p